# Change Integer Order on x-axis for Matplotlib (For more intuitive time-series representation)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot data for the last 6 months, by week. On the x-axis (week number), this causes the week to look like (..., 7, 8, 9, 35, 36, 37...) which is obviously not as intuitive to the viewer for time-series data. Current code for plotting:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
sns.barplot(data=Data, x='Week', y='Value')
plt.title('Title')
plt.xlabel('Week')
plt.ylabel('Value')
```

How can I set a custom axis that will follow the the more intuitive pattern:
`weeklyOrder = list(range(35,53)) + list(range(10))`

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I found the `order` parameter for Seaborn, which seems to address this. Therefore,

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
sns.barplot(data=Data, x='Week', y='Value', order=weeklyOrder)
plt.title('Title')
plt.xlabel('Week')
plt.ylabel('Value')
```

returns the desired output.